# Boss who talk in Hage-che

Tags: speech-levels

Do you feel bosses who talk in Hage-che as opposed to Hae-che are showing more respect to their employees ?

For instance this an example from **Korean Grammar in Use [Book 3]**:

> A: 부장님.
>
> 오늘 저녁 회식은 어디에서 합니까?
>
> B:  자네는 뭘 먹고 싶은가?
>
> 자네가 정해서 식당을 예약하도록 하게.

My translation:

*A: Manager.*

*Where are you having dinner tonight?*

*B: What do you want to eat?*

*You decide and make a restaurant reservation.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 'hage' is more polite than 'hae'. But note that 'hage-che' is quite old-fashioned, so young people hardly use it, and also 자네 too.

Even though using hae-che, you can express enough respect to your employees, by showing your nice behaviors at all time.